# How to receive a NSNotification when the Skype app is receiving/making a call?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, skype, nsnotification

I'd love to know how can I get a notification on my app when Skype is receiving or making a new call. I've been trying to mess around with `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` notifications but I just can't get any from Skype. I've even tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983223/skype-mac-api-use-applescript-or-5-year-old-api) but without any success.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can't just wish notifications into existence. You can only get insight into the behavior of the Skype app if the Skype app is cooperating by broadcasting what it's doing (via notifications or another mechanism). It seems unlikely that the Skype app would do that.

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you. It's just that some friends told me they used some Mac apps before that would pause music (and stuff like that) when a new call started. Just wondering if it's still possible.

Comment: iTunes is doing this for sure (pauses music on Skype in/out calls)

Answer (score 1):

You need to find out if Skype is actually sending these notifications. This it not something you can just hook into. The application has to broadcast a notification when a call is being made or received.

Look in the Skype API documentation to see what it broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few possibilities.

1. You find that Skype publishes such a Notification. Check their docs and contact them to ask.
2. You fiddle with Accessibilty APIs and see if there is a consistent way to determine that a Skype call is being made. This may not work and might be fragile.
3. You do something more low level determining and watching for network and file system behavior of Skype. This is even more fragile. You might find an app like Little Snitch helpful among others to do this level of reversing.
4. You build a SIMBL plugin to inject and handle code. This is more fragile and may introduce unforeseen problems for users. It might not even work depending on how Skype works.